# Crystal Reports XI - convert csv input string parameter to number array for use in record selection formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report which I'm working on which has an input parameter (strSchoolIds) that is a string of comma separated list of unique schoolIds. I'd like to convert this string into a number array which can then be used in the record selection formula. Here is what I've come up with so far. But whenever I view the report just the first schoolId gets used.

Example input string for strSchoolIds might be  `1,3,63,237,281`
The resulting SQL query I'd like would be similiar to this

```
Select name, phone, numStudents 
from schools
where schoolId in (1,3,63,237,281) and active =1
```

My current code is:

```
StringVar Array schools := Split ({?strSchoolIds}, ",");
Local NumberVar arrLen := UBound( schools );
Local NumberVar i := 1;

NumberVar Array schoolIdsArray;
While i <= arrLen Do
(
    schoolIdsArray[i] = ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));
    i := i + 1;
);


{Schools.schoolId} in schoolIdsArray
and {Schools.active} = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got code similar to the:

```
{Schools.schoolId} in schoolIdsArray
```

and it works properly.

Are you sure your array is getting populated properly?

You can test this quickly by adding a new unbound string field and placing this in the formula

```
ToText(schoolIdsArray[1]) + ", " + ToText(schoolIdsArray[2])
```

Comment: I started with trying to create a formula field as suggested but received the error ``. So then I created a formula field on the schools string array and it displays correctly when I specify the index. I followed this idea through and displayed the values for 
    ToText(UBound( schools ));
    ToText(arrLen);
i before and after the while control structure 
    ToText(i);
All values came back correct.

When Crystal Reports gets to the statement 
    schoolIdsArray[i] = ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));
it chokes with the error `A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array`

Comment: oops - the first error received was `A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array `

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after using Nathan Koop's suggestion and building upon it to debug with. Turns out I needed to `Redim` the schoolIdsArray with the arrLen of the string Array `schools` before adding values to it.

```
StringVar Array schools := Split ({?strSchoolIds}, ",");
Local NumberVar arrLen := UBound( schools );
Local NumberVar i := 1;
NumberVar Array schoolIdsArray;
Redim schoolIdsArray[arrLen];
While i <= arrLen Do
(
    schoolIdsArray[i] = ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));
    i := i + 1;
);

{Schools.schoolId} in schoolIdsArray
and {Schools.active} = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this part of the code, I added a colon and it worked...

```
schoolIdsArray[i] := ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that there is a little error in the above code:

> schoolIdsArray[i] = ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));

This should be:

> schoolIdsArray[i] **:=** ToNumber(Trim(schools[i]));